# API POST calls to upload a List of objects containing IFormFile

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm using `IFormFile` from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to build a file upload web service call. Because I need specific data associated with every file upload, I created a custom model class to contain the data with an `IFormFile` property.

```
public class Document
{
    public string FileId { get; set; }
    public string FileTitle { get; set; }
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }

    public IFormFile Content { get; set; }
}
```

The below works fine when only one Document is being uploaded.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("UploadDoc")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DocumentUpload ([FromForm] Document document) { }
```

However, I wish to accept a list of Documents to be uploaded at once. When I configure my POST to accept a list, it no longer works. I know for a fact that `IList<IFormFile>` works, but the issue is that I need additional data for each file.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("UploadDoc")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DocumentUpload ([FromForm] IList<Document> document) { }
```

I am testing my API using Postman and I've included a screenshot of my form-data call. When executed, my Postman will hang. Oddly enough, when I remove the IFormFile property from my Document class, the call works. Can I make this work or is there a workaround?

[Postman call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLWrd.jpg)

Comment: Not really sure if `IList<Document>` will work, but you can try passing base64 encoded file content as string.

Answer (score 3):

It's a known [bug](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4802#issuecomment-456117442)

As a workaround, you can wrap the `IFormFile` in another class and it will work

```
    public class Company
    {
        public IList<Person> Employees { get; set; } = new List<Person>();
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public FormFileWrapper IdImage { get; set; }
    }

    public class FormFileWrapper
    {
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    }
```

then you don have to add the index in your html

```
<form action="http://localhost:5000/api/Values" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p><input type="file" name="Employees[0].IdImage.File"></p>
    <p><input type="file" name="Employees[1].IdImage.File"></p>
    <p><button type="submit">Submit</button></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually [a bug in ASP.NET Core 2.2](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4802), but there is a work-around for it.

Include the Index of the item into your form post, like this:

**Html form**:

```
<input type="hidden" name="document.Index" value="0" />
<input type="file" name="document.Content[0]" />

<input type="hidden" name="document.Index" value="1" />
<input type="file" name="document.Content[1]" />
```

**API call**:

```
key                    value
document.Index         0
document.Content[0]    (binary)
document.Index         1
document.Content[1]    (binary)
```

I have created a [reproduction of the bug](https://github.com/avanveelen/AspNetCoreModelBindingBug) and included [the work-around](https://github.com/avanveelen/AspNetCoreModelBindingBug/blob/master/ListBindingAspNetCoreBug/ListBindingAspNetCoreBug/Pages/Index.cshtml#L28).

Comment: this workaround will work. but it's kind of dangerous because you'll give the ability the API consumer to send you requests without passing the index field which will make the request goes in infinite loop and potentially down the API.
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4802#issuecomment-455985630

Answer (score 0):

For passing List Object from postman to api, you could try struct like `parameterName[index].fieldName`.

Here is a demo which works for you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried this but I don't think the dot notation works. The data isn't being passed through this way

Comment: @jmak24 This is my test [project](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/blob/b1b3f52aa198bdfe783a0b23ee36ec5ff3125496/ModelBindingPro/Controllers/BinderController.cs#L37), make a test and share the difference.

Comment: @TaoZhou if you have the IFormFile in a nested navigation collection it will not work till now it's not fixed bug https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4802

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you try a concrete implementation of IFormFile. And use that concrete type as list parameter.

```
public class Document : IFormFile
{
    public string ContentType => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public string ContentDisposition => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public IHeaderDictionary Headers => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public long Length => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public string Name => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public string FileName => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public void CopyTo(Stream target)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task CopyToAsync(Stream target, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Stream OpenReadStream()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You can customize your class as well by adding required properties.
It's worth trying. Give a try and let me know how do you go.